# Valgrind memcheck - get ??? instead of method names

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, memcheck

I'm running valgrind/memcheck trying to identify a potential memory leakage that causes unexplained segmentation faults.

The log shows ??? instead of method names, so the call stack is useless. All the code (libraries and executable) is compiled with debug info.

Example:

```
==123100== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==123100==    at 0xA7DBD9E: ??? (in /proj/systemc/2.3.2/gcc9.1/lib64/libsystemc-2.3.2.so)
==123100==    by 0xE6E9BE: ??? (in /proj/users/ae/mxx/build/Debug/bin/mxx)
==123100==    by 0xE6DA8E: ??? (in /proj/users/ae/mxx/build/Debug/bin/mxx)
==123100==    by 0x187B22CF: ???
==123100==    by 0x7FEFD40CF: ???
==123100==    by 0xA802BBF: ??? (in /proj/systemc/2.3.2/gcc9.1/lib64/libsystemc-2.3.2.so)
==123100==    by 0xE6C649: ??? (in /proj/users/ae/mxx/build/Debug/bin/mxx)
==123100==    by 0x1893E1A7: ???
==123100==    by 0x187B1E5F: ???
==123100==    by 0x1101: ???
==123100==    by 0x2FBD: ???
==123100==    by 0x1E51001F: ???
```

The valgrind command is:

> valgrind/3.7.0/bin/valgrind --tool=memcheck -q --log-file=/proj/users/ae/valgrind.txt --trace-children=no --child-silent-after-fork=yes --run-libc-freeres=yes --demangle=yes --num-callers=12 --error-limit=no --show-below-main=no --max-stackframe=2000000 --fullpath-after= --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=no --leak-resolution=high --freelist-vol=10000000 --workaround-gcc296-bugs=no --partial-loads-ok=no --undef-value-errors=yes /proj/users/ae/mxx/build/Debug/bin/mxx

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a more recent version of Valgrind. 3.7.0 is very old.
2. Severely prune the options that you are using. Get the tool to work properly, *then* consider adding options. Further, for the following

- --tool=memcheck
- --trace-children=no
- --run-libc-freeres=yes
- --demangle=yes
- --show-below-main=no
- --workaround-gcc296-bugs=no
- --undef-value-errors=yes

  you are redundantly specifying the default values. (Or at least, the default values for current [3.16.1 at the time of writing] Valgrind).